# Amazon Textract JSON missing some pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I am using amazon textract to analyse pdf documents using the async APIs of amazon textract. After I perform the operations, in some cases the output Textract JSON is missing a few pages. What is the reason for missing a few files?

Ex:
In this document, it has 4 pages.

[image]

But the extraction information is only available for 2 pages.

[image]

This is the document information
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `NextToken` . When `NextToken` is populated you need to make another call to get the next segment of results. When `NextToken` is `null`, you have all the results.

I'm using CLI but

`aws textract get-document-analysis --next-token FLpA6... --job-id 12345....`